# Stored procedure set on sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have procedure where I select data .

```
SELECT my_id FROM myDB WHERE @u_id = [u_id]
```

now i need something like :

```
if my_id = 1

set @anotherID = '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @my_Id int    
SELECT @my_Id = my_id FROM myDB WHERE @u_id = [u_id] 

if(@my_ID = 1)

BEGIN
set @anotherID = '10' 
END
```

Comment: do you realize that your `NUMERIC(18,0)` ID uses 9 bytes of storage, which is complete overkill (and wastes cache RAM) unless you think 2.14 billion values that a regular 4 byte INT yields is insufficient .  Also, your UPDATE is completely wrong. `SET @Variable=value` or `UPDATE Table SET Column=value` but not `UPDATE Table SET @Variable=value` like you have.

Answer (score 0):

declare @anotherId int

Select @anotherId  =  (case when my_id = 1 then 10 else @anotherId   End )

From @u_id = [u_id]

Comment: what data type is `@u_id`? a table variable or some sort of int/numeric ID?  you are using it in the context of a table variable: `FROM @u_id`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and I'm not sure what you are really after, but try something like this:

```
--your existing code
SELECT my_id FROM myDB WHERE @u_id = [u_id] --returns a result set,
                                            -- of possibly many rows

--add this
if exists (select 1 from myDB WHERE @u_id = [u_id] AND my_id=1)
BEGIN
   SET @anotherID = '10' --hopefully you have declared this variable
                         --if @anotherID is a int/numeric data type 
                         --  you should just use: SET @anotherID = 10
                         --  notice the removed quotes
END
```